# How to sync playlist to Samsung Galaxy S3 from Kies?

Tags: music, samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I just got my new Galaxy S3 today (after a couple of years using BB and iOS) and I installed Samsung Kies on my computer. Kies's interface is quite intuitive (laying out everything almost the same like iTunes) so I created a few playlists and dragged a few songs to each playlist. Then I clicked on the icon for my phone and selected `Sync > Multimedia > Sync Music > Selected Playlist`, chose all the playlists I wanted And clicked `Sync`.

It transfered quite fast, but when I checked the phone I found all my songs, but no playlists. I tried searching just now to find an answer, and it appears there are other poeple with the same problem. Some people mentioned some paid app or software to do this, but I don't want to buy an extra app just to do this job. I'd also like to avoid having to re-create the playlists manually on my phone.

Could anyone point out what I am missing, or a way around this problem?

Comment: Better... Manage your playlists in Winamp on PC and sync it with Android device using Winamp app. It's free solution without glitch..

Comment: The only problem with that is that Winamp's UI makes iTunes look awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have the same problem with Kies, all music but no playlists!
I tried WinAmp but no luck there either, it did crash alot on my PC, and S3.

So i tried a few other apps on play store, I'm using Easy Phone Tunes, i paid just over £1.00 for it, now it does all ther playlists... But.. out of 2226 tracks it syncs about 1980 tracks. 
However it gives me a list of all that it won't copy, it's a shame i can't copy/paste info from that list.
I know it won't copy DRM Tracks, but i only have about 3 of those that i've bought from iTunes anyway.
I've emailed the DEV of the Easy Phone Tunes app for the PC & S3, i'm running sync again now to generate a log file to send him.

Comment: thanks homestoned .. I hope Samsung would improve/fix Kies that in future releases and I hope it happens soon

Answer (score 1):

Same Issue.  On my old android phone the best solution for me was Songbird with the Folder Sync plugin.  Unfortunately Samsung Galaxy S3 only supports MTP mode and not mass storage mode, and folder sync will not work in MTP mode.

I have tried several desktop players and they all fail to syn playlists properly: Windows Media Player, Songbird, Media Monkey, and WinAmp.  They all have the same problem, they create the play lists in the playlist folder and if you click on them they look OK but when you open them in the phone's player no songs.

I did find an interesting post for creating .m3u files with a script and copying them to your music folder here: http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/583712-syncing-music-playlists-galaxy-s3.html

Turns out that Songbird + Folder Sync plugin will create the right kind of m3u playlists so you can stage what you want on your phone using Folder Sync then cut and paste it into the phones music folder using Windows Explorer.

Comment: I updated my response hopefully this is more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since we can't transfer the playlist directly from the PC the alternative is to store the songs that you need in a playlist onto the mobile in a **folder**. Then create a playlist on the mobile and when you have to add the songs transfer the songs from the folder containing the specific songs. Until Samsung makes the playlist transfer feature same as iPhone, this seems to me the only method available for the moment.